# Script to read and compare registry entries

Tags: powershell, registrykey

I am very new to PowerShell and I am getting stuck on this question.

- Read the registry entries from both of the locations named in the
  project description.
     HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run 
     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run
- Compare each entry to a list of acceptable    entries. The acceptable
  entry list is from a text file named    "Acceptable_Reg.txt" that
  will accompany the script when the script    is downloaded.
- Produce a text file report that lists all    unacceptable registry
  entries. Save the report using the computer    name as the file name.
- Transmit the report file to the following    intranet address: 
  intranet.xyzcompany.com/bad_reg.aspx

I have come up with this so far...but I don't think this is the right way to go about it. I know I will probably need to use the compare-object cmdlet but am unsure how to apply it.

```
$path1 ="HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
$path2 = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
$destination = "(FileName.txt)"
$results = Get-ItemProperty $path1 $path2
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated because my professor is unable to provide me any type of help with the actual script.

Comment: What are "both of the locations named in the project description"?  What is the format of `Acceptable_Reg.txt`?  What results does your code produce?  I can see that your first line should be `$path ="HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"` (note the colon and backslashes).

Comment: If I could get help on the compare task that would be most helpful. I am just lost. I have seen things like PS C:\> $file1  PS C:\> $file2 compare-object $file1 $file2 but was unsure if this would work for registry entries?

Comment: @NewCoder04, yes that should work to get the differences as long you have exported both reg files. e.g 
`Compare-Object $(Get-Content "$location1\file1.reg") $(Get-Content "$location2\file2.reg") | Out-File "c:\temp\differences.txt"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comparing if you have exported the reg files, you can do:

```
$location1 = "C:\temp\location1";
$location2 = "C:\temp\location2";
$location3 = "C:\temp";

Compare-Object $(Get-Content "$location1\file1.reg") $(Get-Content "$location2\file2.reg") | 
    Where-Object { IsNotAccepted($_.InputObject) } | 
    Out-File "$location3\NotAcceptedEntries.txt" -Force

function IsNotAccepted($entry){
    $accepted = $false;
    # $name = $entry.Split('=')[0]
    # $value = $entry.Split('=')[1]

    # Put your logics here

    return -Not($accepted);
}
```

Note that `$_.InputObject` represents the entry, e.g.

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe.FriendlyAppName"="7-Zip
>   Console 2"

You also can know in which file was that by checking `$_.SideIndicator`. If it returns `=>` it means right file (file2.reg) has that difference. Conversely `<=` means the difference was found in left file (file1.reg).

Comment: This was most helpful. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain things for me. It has been a learning endeavor for that's for sure.